# Is it possible to play Scrolls offline?

Tags: scrolls

Since Scrolls have a single player component I was wondering if it is possible to play the game without an Internet connection?

In Minecraft (from the same developer) you can select offline mode in the login screen but I can't seem to find a similar option in Scrolls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, offline play isn't possible.  This is because all of the game creation, game connection handling and AI calculations are done on Mojang's servers.  This is to prevent any form of cheating of the game.

Yes, it would be nice to see if Mojang would create a system where you could play offline against an AI and, to keep it fair, not get anything for your efforts.  However, at the moment, I can't find anything (official or otherwise) stating that Mojang hopes to implement such a feature.

Comment: I asked at the Scrolls forums too and got pretty much the same reason: prevention of cheating/hacking. As far as I can tell, it shouldn't take too much work to implement offline mode though, just by disabling all rewards and the store.

Answer (score -2):

No for 2 reasons.

1. It's a MMORPG-Kinda the MMO proves that it won't run offline.
2. You connect to servers to play, like World Of Warcraft you have servers that people play on.

This isn't a 100% "right" answer but this is from what I read in the past.

Comment: As a sidenote, please don't add signatures or taglines to your answers.  They're fluff, and are not needed.

Comment: Not my down vote, but I'm asking about single player that shouldn't require a connection to function properly.

Comment: This isn't a single player game, and won't have single player. Everything will run online.

Comment: @Wojtek'Charkz'Hordyniec: You are incorrect in your comment. There is in fact a Single Player mode available with Quick Match against easy, medium or hard AI and as well as the "Trials" challenges. However, you are correct in noting that even this mode requires a connection.

Comment: When I read the information on this game. These kind of stuff was never mentioned. Only mentioned that it would run on servers online. I did say at the bottom. "This isn't a 100% the right answer"